# Android Error: App not installed as package appears to be invalid when trying to install debug APK

Tags: android-studio

I am an Android developer working on a project. Our team recently published an Android app to the Google Play Store, but due to a human error, we lost the upload keystore of the app. Our client is already using the app, so we requested an update to the upload keystore, which was updated successfully yesterday.

Before publishing the updated app to the Play Store, we tried to install the debug APK on our smartphones to check if everything was working correctly. However, we are facing an issue where the installation terminates with the error message "App not installed as package appears to be invalid."

I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue, but the error persists:

- We also tried release apk after signing it but still it did not worked.
- Ensured that I am installing the correct debug APK that was built using the updated upload keystore
- Enabled installation from unknown sources in my smartphone's security settings
- Uninstalled the existing version of the app from my smartphone before installing the updated debug APK

I am not sure what else to try. Can someone please help me diagnose and resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: did u manage to fix it? My app is working on Android 11 but not Android 13